# model problem after rendering

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

### after rendering from blender it showing this dots

everything was clear in viewport i don't know what should i do, i checked object in edit mode and every object was complete and clear

rendering in cycles
[image: blender render problem]
and here is my render settings

[image: render settings]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Of your have subdivision surface modifier attached ti One of your object check if render and preview subdivision are the same